# Access violation reading location 0xcdcdcdcd. C++

Tags: c++, memory, unhandled-exception

Essentially what I'm trying to do at this point is build a program to allow you to pick from 3 different classes (Tank, Mele, Ranged) when you pick the class you would then give it a name of 20 or fewer chars. After picking 5 classes and giving each champ a name it would print out the name and health of each class you picked. code stands like this:

```
#include "Driver.h"
#include <stdio.h> 
#include "Mele.h"
#include "Ranged.h"
#include "Tank.h"

int main(void)
{

Champion *champ[5];
int i, choice;

printf("Enter the number for which class you would like to add to your team\n");
for(i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
{
    char name[20];
    //printf("Enter the number for which class you would like to add to your team");
    printf("1 = Tank\n");
    printf("2 = Ranged\n");
    printf("3 = Mele\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &choice);
    if(choice == 1)
    {
        printf("Give him a name!\n");
        scanf("%s", name);
        champ[i] = new Tank(name);
    }
    else if(choice == 2){
        printf("Give him a name!\n");
        scanf("%s", name);
        champ[i] = new Ranged(name);
    }
    else if(choice == 3){
        printf("Give him a name!\n");
        scanf("%s", name);
        champ[i] = new Mele(name);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You did not enter a number between 1 and 3 please try again!\n");
        i = i - 1;
    }
}
for(i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
{
    printf("%s has %f health", champ[i]->getName(), champ[i]->getHealth());
}
return 0;
}
```

That's the main function

The champion class looks like:

```
Champion::Champion(void)
{
}
Champion::Champion(char name1[])
{ 
    name = name1;
}

char* Champion::getName(void)
{   
    return name;
}   

double Champion::getHealth(void)
{
    return health;
}

int Champion::getFluid(void)
{
    return fluid;
}

double Champion::getArmor(void)
{
    return armor;
}

double Champion::getSpecialA(void)
{
    return specialA;
}

double Champion::getDamage(void)
{
    return physDamage;
}

void Champion::setHealth(double health1)
{
    health = health1;
}
void Champion::setFluid(int fluid1)
{
    fluid = fluid1;
} 
void Champion::setArmor(double armor1)
{
    armor = armor1;
}
void Champion::getSpecialA(double specialA1)
{
    specialA = specialA1;
}
void Champion::setDamage(double physDamage1)
{
    physDamage = physDamage1;
}
```

Then i have 4 other classes called Tank, Ranged and Mele; all of these inherit from Champion and have the same set up as Champion. when i run the program i get this:

```
'dragons_rage.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Tom\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\dragons_rage\Debug\dragons_rage.exe', Symbols loaded.
'dragons_rage.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'dragons_rage.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'dragons_rage.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'dragons_rage.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
First-chance exception at 0x5dfc14cf (msvcr100d.dll) in dragons_rage.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcdcdcdcd.
Unhandled exception at 0x5dfc14cf (msvcr100d.dll) in dragons_rage.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcdcdcdcd.
The program '[516] dragons_rage.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005).
```

Im not exactly sure what these errors are and what they mean if i could get some help that would be amazing thank you!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable char name[20] is not valid after leaving the first for()

You should copy the value of the array in the constructor to an array inside Champion or dynamically allocate memory for the name.

This is one option:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

class Champion {
  char name[20];

 public:

 Champion(const char theName[],int size ){

  for( int i=0;i < size; i++ ){
    name[i] = theName[i];
  }
 }
 const char* getName(){
  return name;
 }
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]){

 Champion *c;
 const char name[] = "vamos";
 c = new Champion(name,strlen(name));
 printf("%s",c->getName());
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One thing that jumps out at me is the Champion constructor:

```
Champion::Champion(char name1[])
{
}
```

This doesn't do anything with the character array -- it doesn't initialize any "name" member. WHen the name is handed out later, is it null, or worse, garbage? You presumably need to copy that argument into your member variable, so you have a name you can use later.

Comment: Also for future reference 0xcdcdcdcd usually means you're pointing to uninitialized memory. So that's usually a good indication you forgot to set something up.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help implementing string.h fixed the problem along with the fact that i wasn't initializing memory. what i ended up doing was doing a malloc for the name in the champion constructor to set the size of the string name that was being implemented! Thank you everyone for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Your loop only runs 4 times, so the last Champion pointer is never initialized.

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
```

Should be changed to:

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

Also none of the members of your Champion class are initialized in the constructor, so reading them will cause undefined behaviour.

The code you wrote is more or less C with classes. Look up std::string, it will make your code much simpler and more correct. As it is right now, your program contains multiple buffer overflow vulnerabilities and dangling pointers.

If I were evil, I would create a Tank with a name much longer than 20 characters and likely be able to crash your program or worse, execute arbitrary code by overwriting your text segment.

Comment: no it still runs 5 times 0 to 4 goes a whole 5 times because you start at 0 and then 1 and then 2 etc all the way to 4. and you have to go from 0 to 5 because all arrays start at 0 not 1

Comment: @Ziekle, The way you have your for loop will only access `0` to `3` but **not** `4`. Either change it to what said in this answer, or to `<= 4`

Comment: @Zieklecknerizer Nope, the loop will never run with i = 4 since you are using the strictly-less operator.

Comment: Zohmahgoodness ya got me there haha i always forget that = ! thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately i did as you said and set it to <= 4 so now it will get through all of the inputs but breaks before the outputs so im not sure what the problem is now

Answer (score 0):

check the

```
return name;
```

in

```
Champion::getName()
```

where is name defined?
Is it initialized?

---

When you do `name = name1` in the constructor, you are just copying the pointer.
In the case of your program, this is a pointer to a local variable in your for loop.
That variable goes out of scope once you leave that for loop.
You should use [std::string::copy()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/copy/) or [strcpy()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/) to copy your string.

Comment: Name is defined in the header file and it gets initialized in the constructor. i would have put in the header but i did not want to put in toooooo much info lulz

Answer (score 0):

Make it a habit to set the  pointer members to 0 (NULL) is the constructor if they are not pointing to any address on the heap or on the stack. Doing this will save you from the 0xcc... invalid addresses. If you are done with the pointer even if the pointer is part of a double pointer, set it back to 0 after free the object which it points to. It is your responsibility which writing the code to do so. The other option is go do a managed memory programming language instead.

And with your code, it's

```
Champion** champ = (Champion**)malloc(sizeof(Champion*) * 5);
// or
Champion** champ = (Champion**)calloc(5, sizeof(Champion*));
// or
Champion** champ = new Champion*[5];
```

Which way you choose to allocation the champ double pointer is up to you. I prefer `(Champion**)malloc(sizeof(Champion*) * 5)` because I am used to C style coding.